# How can I index a lot of txt files? (Java/C/C++)

Tags: java, c++, c, full-text-search

I need to index a lot of text. The search results must give me the name of the files containing the query and all of the positions where the query matched in each file - so, I don't have to load the whole file to find the matching portion. What libraries can you recommend for doing this?

**update**: Lucene has been suggested. Can you give me some info on how should I use Lucene to achieve this? (I have seen examples where the search query returned only the matching files)

Comment: Does the query only contain one word ? Or are you expecting to directly find whole paragraphs ?

Comment: The query can contain several words.

Comment: When a query contains several words, will you expect them to be found in the same order in the returned files, or not necessarily ?

Comment: I need them to be found in the same order. Even a one-word approach would help as I can try to match the surrounding for each one-word match.

Comment: That's the option i considered for multiple-word queries.

Comment: Are you limited to free solutions? there are commercial libraries that will probably provide all search capabilities you'll ever need.

Comment: Yes, no commercial libs please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the lucene term for what you are looking for is [highlighting](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/package-summary.html). Here is [a very recent report on Lucene highlighting](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/02/17/highlighting-highlighter-thoughts/). You will probably need to store word position information in order to get the snippets you are looking for. The [Token API](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Token.html) may help.

Answer (score 8):

For java try [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/)

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on how you are going to access it. And of course, how many are going to access it. Read up on [MapReduce](http://labs.google.com/papers/mapreduce.html).

If you are going to roll your own, you will need to create an index file which is sort of a map between unique words and a tuple like (file, line, offset). Of course, you can think of other in-memory data structures like a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)(prefix-tree) a [Judy array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judy_array) and the like...

Some 3rd party solutions are listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search#Text_retrieval_software).

Answer (score 2):

[Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/) - Java

It's open source as well so you are free to use and deploy in your application.

As far as I know, [Eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/) help file is powered by Lucene - It is tested by millions

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://www.compass-project.org/ it can be looked on as a  wrapper on top of Lucene, Compass simplifies common usage patterns of Lucene such as google-style search, index updates as well as more advanced concepts such as caching and index sharding (sub indexes). Compass also uses built in optimizations for concurrent commits and merges.

The Overview can give you more info
http://www.compass-project.org/overview.html

I have integrated this into a spring project in no time. It is really easy to use and gives what your users will see as google like results.

Answer (score 2):

Also take a look at [Lemur Toolkit](http://www.lemurproject.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try and construct a state machine by reading all files ? Transitions between states will be letters, and states will be either final (some files contain the considered word, in which case the list is available there) or intermediate.

As far as multiple-word lookups, you'll have to deal with them independently before intersecting the results.

I believe the [Boost::Statechart](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/statechart/doc/tutorial.html) library may be of some help for that matter.

Comment: I don't see how a state machine would be efficient.

Comment: Why not ? In case it wouldn't be as efficient as you'd want, you could add more complicated transitions (strings). It's simply a binary tree. You can decide its size and balance it as much as you like !

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware you asked for a library, just wanted to point you to the underlying concept of [building an inverted index](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/a-first-take-at-building-an-inverted-index-1.html) (from [Introduction to Information Retrieval](http://www-csli.stanford.edu/~hinrich/information-retrieval-book.html) by Christopher D. Manning, Prabhakar Raghavan and Hinrich Schütze).